# Woocommerce webhooks not firing at all

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, kubernetes, webhooks

I currently have mysql server, small node express application and wordpress running on kubernetes on my local machine. The connections between the pods work well with their cluster IP addresses, there is no problem in that.

I created a webhook for coupon created event with the delivery address http://10.101.78.224:8080 which is reachable from the wordpress pod when I tried with ssh. The hook is created successfully but it never fires at all just like all other webhooks I tried. I have my node js + express app logging all the requests and nothing shows up just like nothing shows up in the woocommerce log so the hook just isn't firing as it should.

I am using the wordpress:4.8-apache and mysql:5.6 images.

The rest API works well from my node pod and it returns info so the problem is exclusively with the webhooks not firing, other things are working fine.